# ANDROID: How do I filter a list of Contacts with a CursorLoader based on a list of standardized phone numbers

Tags: java, android

I have a list of phone numbers that I have stripped to all be just the ten digits. I want to use that list to filter on a cursor, but I cannot get the incoming list into the same format (just the ten digit number). I can't use `PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI` because that can only compare against one phone number, and same with the `PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL(` sqlite function. This is what I have so far as my selection statement:

`Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY +
                        "<>''" + " AND " + Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + "=1" +
                        " AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " IN (" +
                        TextUtils.join(",", Collections.nCopies(registeredPhoneNumbers.size(), "?")) + ")";`

It is currently working for some phone numbers, but not others (depending on how I saved the contact's phone number). Any ideas on how I can get the filter to work using the CursorLoader?

Answer (score 0):

Not fully tested but you could use (or something based upon this) to drop non-numerics and return a single column.

The source table in this case was (so phonenumber is the relevant column):-

[image]

The SQL :-

```
SELECT digit1||digit2||digit3||digit3||digit5||digit6||digit7||digit8||digit9||digit10||digit11||digit12||digit13||digit14 AS converted  FROM
(SELECT 
substr(phonenumber,1,1) AS testdigit1, length(phonenumber),
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,1,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,1,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,1,1)  END AS digit1,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,2,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,1,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,2,1)  END AS digit2,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,3,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,1,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,3,1)  END AS digit3 ,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,4,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,1,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,4,1)  END AS digit4,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,5,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,1,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,5,1)  END AS digit5,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,6,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,6,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,6,1)  END AS digit6,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,7,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,7,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,7,1)  END AS digit7,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,8,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,8,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,8,1)  END AS digit8,
CASE
    WHEN substr(phonenumber,9,1) < '0' OR substr(phonenumber,9,1) > '9' THEN '' ELSE substr(phonenumber,9,1)  END AS digit9,
CASE 
    WHEN length(phonenumber) >= 10 AND substr(phonenumber,10,1) >= '0' AND substr(phonenumber,10,1) <= '9' THEN substr(phonenumber,10,1) ELSE '' END AS digit10,
CASE 
    WHEN length(phonenumber) >= 11 AND substr(phonenumber,11,1) >= '0' AND substr(phonenumber,11,1) <= '9' THEN substr(phonenumber,11,1) ELSE '' END AS digit11,
CASE 
    WHEN length(phonenumber) >= 12 AND substr(phonenumber,12,1) >= '0' AND substr(phonenumber,12,1) <= '9' THEN substr(phonenumber,12,1) ELSE '' END AS digit12,
CASE 
    WHEN length(phonenumber) >= 13 AND substr(phonenumber,13,1) >= '0' AND substr(phonenumber,13,1) <= '9' THEN substr(phonenumber,13,1) ELSE '' END AS digit13,
CASE 
    WHEN length(phonenumber) >= 14 AND substr(phonenumber,14,1) >= '0' AND substr(phonenumber,14,1) <= '9' THEN substr(phonenumber,14,1) ELSE '' END AS digit14
FROM phonenumbers)
```

- Obviously the switch to checking the length of the phonenumber would be used to handle the smallest possible length.
- This assumes a maximum of 14 characters if more then simply add accordingly.

You'd just incoporate this, appropriately changed (if I understand correctly  to replace ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER).

Applying the SQL above results in :-

[image]